# App-provided Voice Action on Android 5.0.1 Device NOT Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, voice-recognition

Having come back to Android programming after some time away I'm currently investigating whether I can create a custom 'App-provided' voice action that will work on an Android phone.

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided) a custom voice action can be added but it appears to imply it only works on a 'Wear' device not a handheld. However as I can use the "OK Google" voice-command to set a timer on my Android 5.0.1 handheld device I wondered if the above link applied  as well, but it appears not when I try it.

Is it the case custom app-provided voice actions are only available via a Wear device?